# Why I cannot see application menus on the 2nd extension screen of Mac?

Tags: macos, display

I work with 2 monitors using the same Mac both at work and at home. At home I use the extension monitor with the 4:3 aspect ratio and I can see the application menus on top of the 2nd screen. At work I am using the monitor with the 16:10 aspect ratio and cannot see the application menus on the top of the 2nd screen.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me when my second screen is a TV. Some screens chop off the edges of the screen.

Here are three things I'd try:

### 1 Mirroring

> - Go to System Preferences » Displays
> - Select "Arrangement"
> - Click "Mirror displays"

[image: Mirror displays]
Image via http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5019

This makes both monitors display the same screen, forcing them to be the same aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio is different, there will be blank space around the image.

### 2 Change screen resolution.

> Go to System Preferences » Displays.
>   Try changing the resolution for your second screen.

The system will ask you to confirm if the settings work, so you don't have to worry about accidentally messing things up. Go nuts.
[image: Changing image resolution.]

Image via [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601608/is-it-possible-for-an-applescript-to-dim-up-0-100-screen-brightness-on-osx-10), since I don't have a second display connected right now.

### 3 Change the settings on the monitor itself.

If the menu bar is still missing, try using the monitor's menu to change the crop settings.

This is isn't as likely with modern monitors, but it's a possibility (especially if you're using a CRT monitor or TV)

#### More notes

If you see a menu bar on top but it's *blank*, the options should appear once you click on that screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say, I'm going to assume you're using 10.9.x (aka, Mavericks).

In the second monitor, simply bring your mouse down to the bottom of the display (or wherever you have your dock) and you should see the dock after a brief delay (less than 2 seconds on my late 2013 MBP).

HTH

Comment: The OP was asking about the application menu, not the dock.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have this work monitor now, cannot try. I remember that the dock also did not appear or it was only one dock on the extension monitor, and no one on the laptop